# stm32 through swd printf doesn't work properly

Tags: printf, stm32, swd

[image]

I modified _write function.
When I use, printf("Hello \n"); in debug mode SWV Console, I get random 1 character like @.

I tried combinations of SWV frequency in debug configuration section.

Comment: Which MCU you are using? what have you modified on _write()? It varies between MCU... Also small-factor Nucleo boards or MCU generally do not support SWO/SWV...

Comment: MCU: stm32f407zet6; 
int _write(int file, char *ptr, int len)
{
  /* Implement your write code here, this is used by puts and printf for example */
  int i=0;
  for(i=0 ; i<len ; i++)
    ITM_SendChar((*ptr++));
  return len;
}
I can run blink function through SWD.

Answer (score 0):

select HSI in PLL Source MUX. it worked for me.